# Trying to understand Pointers to Interfaces and IUnknown::QueryInterface in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, com

I'm currently learning about Component Object Model (COM) and found myself a little bit confused about Interfaces. Got several questions:

1.- Is there any difference between a pointer to a Class and a pointer to an Interface?

2.- Why is that we want to access to an Interface throughout a pointer to it, and not through the instance of the Interface directly?

3.- In [IUnknown - Win32 apps | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/unknwn/nf-unknwn-iunknown-queryinterface(refiid_void)) there is some documentation about `IUnknown::QueryInterface`. What does it stores in `ppvObject`? If we dereference `ppvObject` should we always get the same pointer that we used to call `QueryInterface` independently from the Interface we are querying as long as the Interface is implemented by the calling object?

For example, if we run `pMyObject->QueryInterface(SomeRIID, &pvObject);` then `pvObject` will be equal to `pMyObject` as long as `pMyObject` is a pointer to a class that implements the Interface associated to `SomeRIID`?

Comment: In general you will not have a "class that implements the Interface associated to SomeRIID" as a direct part of your program that is using such a component. The component will not necessarily be running in the same process or address space. pointer to interface gets you to whatever trivial or complex gunk needed to interact and coordinate with the component instance where ever it is and however sophisticated the communication and coordination needs to be.

Comment: So I'd say a pointer to a class instance is totally different from a pointer to an Interface. COM provides for independent, disjoint components that can be used by multiple programs. These are packaged separately and a program that uses them will generally not contain classes that implement them, but may contain classes that wrap the interfaces to them.

Comment: *"Got several questions:"* -- Stack Overflow has a strict limit of one question per question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. COM is language agnostic, so we always get a reference to a COM [`interface`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/midl/interface). The word "class" you use here is bound to the C++ language. How the interface reference was obtained (from a C++ class maybe if the oject implementation is C++) is irrelevant. Some interfaces are obtained from a [`coclass`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/attributes/coclass), others from method calls, including `QueryInterface`. In general, we describe interfaces and coclasses in [IDL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/midl/midl-start-page) files precisely because COM is language agnostic.
2. see 1. If by "instance of the Interface" you mean the C++ vtable/struct behind all this, it's again because it's all language agnostic. But you do get a "COM vtable" ("object layout") behind that pointer, as the COM interface is a binary contract. That binary contract is a *defined ordered* list of methods which a *defined method signature* (a defined ordered list of parameters each with a defined type, and a defined return type, or void), and a *defined calling convention* (usually `stdcall`), for each method.
3. The [IUnknown remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/unknwn/nf-unknwn-iunknown-queryinterface(refiid_void)#remarks) section should contain everything you want to know:

> For any given COM object [...], a specific
> query for the `IUnknown` interface on any of the object's interfaces
> must always return the same pointer value. This enables a client to
> determine whether two pointers point to the same component by calling
> `QueryInterface` with `IID_IUnknown` and comparing the results.
>
> It is specifically not the case that queries for interfaces other than
> `IUnknown` (even the same interface through the same pointer) must
> return the same pointer value.

PS: ok, [it is no coincidence that the Win32 COM object layout matches closely the C++ object layout.](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040205-00/?p=40733)...